# Ckeditor set value to null after clear form

Tags: angular, ckeditor

ckeEditorCommonConfig: any

ckeEditorCommonCongiguration(): void {
this.ckeEditorCommonConfig = {
height: "100%",
extraPlugins: 'codeTag,kbdTag',
removePlugins: "exportpdf",
toolbar: [
{ name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format'] },
{
name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'],
items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', 'RemoveFormat', 'Code']
},
{
name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi'],
items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote']
},
{ name: 'document', groups: ['mode', 'document', 'doctools'], items: ['Source'] },
],
toolbarGroups: [
{ name: 'styles' },
{ name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'] },
{ name: 'document', groups: ['mode', 'document', 'doctools'] },
{ name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi'] },
],
removeButtons: "",
language: 'en',
forcePasteAsPlainText: false,
allowedContent: true,
extraAllowedContent: 'img',
}
}

In html file :

<ckeditor #ckeEditors [config]="ckeEditorCommonConfig" formControlName="comment" appEmptyToNull>

When I reset the form the value of ckediotr not set to null (this.commentForm.reset())
inside commentForm there is field called comment which is used to store ckeditor value.

[image: After form reset the value to ckediotr not remove]

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?  you don't want it to be set to null?

Comment: I have to remove ckeditor data set value empty( data added at place empty) on above image.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to "bind" a variable to the 'data' property:

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor>
```

In this example above, you would bind a variable like this:

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" data="{{ myVariable }}"></ckeditor>
```

Then in the .ts file you declare a public myVariable and set it to null

```
public myVariable: string = null;
```